# how to get Token_Id from ERC721 smart contract

Tags: tokens, erc-721

How do I retriever Token_Id of cryptokitties from ERC721 Smart contract

[image]

Smart contract address : https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code

Answer (score 2):

That `Token_Id` is the index of the `Kitty` instance in the `kitties` array, which, according to the comment in the published smart contract, represents:

```
 /// @dev An array containing the Kitty struct for all Kitties in existence. The ID
    ///  of each cat is actually an index into this array. Note that ID 0 is a negacat,
    ///  the unKitty, the mythical beast that is the parent of all gen0 cats. A bizarre
    ///  creature that is both matron and sire... to itself! Has an invalid genetic code.
    ///  In other words, cat ID 0 is invalid... ;-)
    Kitty[] kitties;
```

The `totalSupply()` function in the smart contract returns the total number of kitties in existence.

Comment: Thank Tudor Constanin for your reply but I want to get my own tokenID not total amount.

Answer (score 1):

This is the public interface: https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#readContract. It's hard to understand what you're exactly asking, but that's what there is.

Comment: I want to know how many ERC721 tokens user have